# Fastest way to update a large amount of product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

What's the fastest way to update product data in WooCommerce (200-300 products in at most 2 minutes)?

I tried using WooCommerce's internal API and in my case it only updates 12 products in 30 seconds. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

I also tried using WooCommerce REST API which updated only 4 products in 30 seconds, WordPress database API (8 products in 30 seconds) and sending plain SQL queries to the database (which managed to update around 40 products in 30 seconds but I'm not really comfortable with sending simple SQL queries as I don't think I will be able to ensure that they are completely safe).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted? Is it not clear enough? Or is there another problem with it?

Comment: What do you update each time?

Answer (score 0):

The speed of the rest API call based on the server response you can not change it as your requirements.